# PHP and MySQL Web Development, Second Edition

Tags: apache, url, ssl, call, back

i am trying to get a response  sent to a call back url from a external party.
since the call back url is local (I do not hv external dev box),I am getting my gateway to
forward the response to my local box.I can see the response hitting my local box,but
how do I get apache to redirect to a specific virtual host I hv got in apache(I hv multiple
virtual hosts and the response is ssl)

for eg: the call back url I hv instructed the external party to sent to is my gateway addressin the following format
gatewayIP:port:/process.php.

the gateway then redirects the response it receives to my local IP port 443(SSL).
I can see the packets coming in apache log..

on my local box i hv got two virtual hosts,eg shop.local and api.local.
my quetion is how do i resolve the incoming response to shop.local/process.php

hope this is clear and  really appreciate any help and advice...

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand the issue without concrete examples (you should consider adding your configuration), but I'll take a shot.

It sounds like your local Apache is receiving a request to, say, 192.168.1.5.  With just an IP in the request, you really only get to decide one of your two local vhosts to redirect traffic to for each port, and you can do this by specifying the IP address as the `ServerName` or as a `ServerAlias` for the `VirtualHost` you want to accept the request.

Your configuration might look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin asdf@example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/shop/www
    ServerName shop.local
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.5
    ErrorLog /path/toerror_log
    CustomLog /path/to/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin asdf@example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/api/www
    ServerName api.local
    ErrorLog /path/toerror_log
    CustomLog /path/to/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```